# How do I update the text inside a textblock everytime I enter something in a textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I now have a WPF app which gives me the result I wanted. It reads the texts inside the three textboxes "aValue", "bValue" and "cValue" and use those to print a quadratic equation inside the TextBlock "quadEqn". The problem is that I need the textblock to display or update the equation the moment a number is entered inside any of the textboxes.

Here's my xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="aValue" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" Text="" .../>
    <TextBox x:Name="bValue" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" Text="" .../>
    <TextBox x:Name="cValue" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" Text="" .../>

        <TextBlock x:Name="quadEqn" Text="" .../>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sendValuesToEqn();
    }

    public void sendValuesToEqn()
    {
        double a, b, c;
        if(aValue.Text=="") a = 0;
        else a = double.Parse(aValue.Text);

        if (bValue.Text == "") b = 0;
        else b = double.Parse(bValue.Text);

        if (cValue.Text == "") c = 0;
        else c = double.Parse(cValue.Text);

        writeEquation(a, b, c);
    }

    public void writeEquation(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        if(a==0)
        {
            if(b==0)
            {
                if(c==0)
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = c.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(c==0)
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = b + "x";
                }
                else
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = b + "x + " + c;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(b==0)
            {
                if(c==0)
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = a + "x\xB2";
                }
                else
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = a + "x\xB2 + " + c;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(c==0)
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = a + "x\xB2 + " + b + "x";
                }
                else
                {
                    quadEqn.Text = a + "x\xB2 + " + b + "x + " + c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem again?

Comment: Example: If I enter 1 into the textbox "aValue", nothing happens yet in the textblock "quadEqn". If I press `Enter` or enter another character in any of the textboxes, that's the time when the textblock will show ``1x2``.

Comment: I want the textblock to show `1x(squared)` or `1x2` the very moment I press `1` inside the textbox "aValue".

Comment: In Visual Studio set a breakpoint to method **TextBox_KeyDown** and check if it hits whenever you enter something in any of the textboxes.

Comment: Few tips: 1) use `string.Empty` instead of `""` 2) if you want to test string on emptyness use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method 3) if you use C# of version 6 or greater it is more readable to use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) instead of concatenation via + 4) according to Microsoft's design guidelines method should start with a capital letter. Also note that `double.Parse` method will throw an exception if text doesn't represent a valid double number (`TryParse` is silent analogue).

Comment: thanks for the tips. i haven't read yet the docs about string methods and properties in the .net library, I'll take a look at them soon. Didn't also know about TryParse up until now, I was actually planning to create a method where a message will show if the entry in the textbox is invalid format. I also realized its better to keep the entries in string format if the purpose is only to display them, and parse them if they're going to be used as numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best solution is to imlement described logic via MVVM rather than via code behind.

In your view model you should create three string properties for each `TextBox`:

```
public string A { get { ... } set { ... } }
public string B { get { ... } set { ... } }
public string C { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Then bind `Text` property of `TextBox`'es to these properties. Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in view-model class and to fire `PropertyChanged` in setters of the view-model properties.

Then create a property for the equation `TextBlock`:

```
public string Equation { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Also fire `PropertyChanged` in setter of this property. Bind `Text` property of the equation `TextBlock` to it.

In setters of `A`, `B`, `C` call a method which will take these three values and will construct an equation. When the equation constructed set it to the `Equation` property of the view-model.

To change equation immidiately as you typing at `TextBox`'es in their bindings set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Comment:  I'll still need to learn the MVVM pattern though. Okay, back to reading

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a Converter:

> Xaml:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="aValue"  Text="" Height="30" Width="100" />
    <TextBox x:Name="bValue"  Text="" Height="30" Width="100" />
    <TextBox x:Name="cValue"  Text="" Height="30" Width="100" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="quadEqn" Height="30" Width="100" Background="BurlyWood">
        <Run Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=aValue,Converter={StaticResource quadraticEquationConverter},ConverterParameter=aValue}"/>            
        <Run Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=bValue,Converter={StaticResource quadraticEquationConverter},ConverterParameter=bValue}"/>            
        <Run Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=cValue,Converter={StaticResource quadraticEquationConverter},ConverterParameter=cValue}"/>
   </TextBlock>
```

> Define Converter in your Window Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:QuadraticEquationConverter x:Key="quadraticEquationConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

> And Your Converter Class:

```
public class QuadraticEquationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        if(parameter.Equals("aValue") && value.ToString() != "")
            return value + "x^2 + ";
        else if(parameter.Equals("bValue") && value.ToString() != "")
            return value + "x + ";
        else
            return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```